# Disable datagrid header rollover color and selection color 

Tags: actionscript, datagrid, header, selection, flex3

How can I remove these two colors from the header? I could override rollover for the columns and leave the selection, but I want to remove these two effects from the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the mx:DataGridColumn set sortable="false". This will disable the highlight rollover of the DataGrid header.